# Facebook Graph API - No Permission to Post to group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Now 9 days ago, i cant post to my group anymore.

I didnt changed something but i cant post to my group anymore!

Does anyone have an idea?

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "error_subcode": 1376025,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Keine Berechtigung zum Posten",
    "error_user_msg": "Du bist nicht berechtigt, in dieser Gruppe zu posten.",
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

That is the message that i get (its german and says no permission to post into the group)

I have "publish_to_group" permission in my app.
I can also post to my site with that APP, but not to my group anymore.
I already reauthorized the app and create new Access Key and something. But doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can your user account still post to the group directly (not via API)? Is your app still installed in the group?

Comment: @CBroe The APP has Permissions to the Site and Groups. The APP hast Site Access and the Site is in the Group as Administator. I can also post in the Group manually as the page. What do you mean with installed in the group? I have publish_to_group permission and i give access to it yes.And yes, my user account can also post to the group. The FB Page/Site and also my user account is admin in the group

Comment: App Installation, as mentioned in the requirements for posting to a group feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms